# Invoking a dos batch file to run on a VM, using cgi, running on apache

Tags: perl, apache, batch-file, cgi, dos

kindly help me here.
My requirement is that we have a VM, on which few dos batch scripts need to be run, based on the parameters chosen on a web page form, which is hosted via Apache on the VM.

I have got Apache running on the VM, & the web page form invoked through browser from a different PC.
On submitting the form, I invoke a .cgi written in perl.

In that .cgi, I would like to invoke the batch scripts to be run on the VM.

Below are the steps that I am follwoing:

**Step 1:**
The HTML form:

```
form action="/cgi-bin/tasks.cgi" method="POST" target="_blank"
```

**Step 2:**

In the file `tasks.cgi` [located in the VM], I want to invoke the dos batch `"C:\events.bat"` which is stored on the VM. The commands in `C:\events.bat` are to be run on the VM. Is this possible?

I've tried `system`, `exec`, `qx`, ``, but none seems to invoke the .bat file.

Kindly advise how to proceed.

Thanks,
Prasanth

tasks.cgi is:

```
#!perl

local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
{
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}else {
$buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}
# Split information into name/value pairs
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
$value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
$FORM{$name} = $value;
}
$proc = $FORM{proc};

############## PLEASE HELP IN THIS SECTION-BEGIN ############################

system("C:\\events\.bat");

############## PLEASE HELP IN THIS SECTION-END ############################

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
print "<head>";
print "<title>The chosen process is being executed</title>";
print "</head>";
print "<body>";
print "<h2> Process is $proc</h2>";
print "</body>";
print "</html>";

1;
```

Comment: Have you tried `system("%ComSpec% /c \"C:\\events\.bat\"")`?  That will run `cmd.exe /c "c:\events.bat"`.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but nowhere in your post do you assert that the VM web server is running on Windows.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Apache runs as a different user, It needs to have permission on that folder for it to read and execute the file in that directory. you can try to place the file in one the "Directory" Directive and try to execute it.  Check Options on Directory that you can use: *http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options*